# Getting post created by an user

Tags: python, django

I want to display all posts created from an user.the problem is that i dont know what to write in kwargs as i do use slug to display user urls.

**models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
body_text=models.TextField()
title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
created_on=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True)
author=models.ForeignKey(
    get_user_model(),
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
    return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfilPostView(ListView):
model=Post
template_name='profile.html'

def get_queryset(self):
     return Post.objects.filter(author=self.kwargs['']).order_by('created_on')
    #return Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user).order_by('created_on')
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('post/<slug:slug>/profile', ProfilPostView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

Comment: Can't you just pass the user ID into your `filter()`?

Comment: You don't need to specify anything for kwargs, just use `return Post.objects.filter(author_id=user_id).order_by('created_on')`

Comment: how do i get the user_id? i dont want the user who is currently logged in but all the users who created a post

Comment: you can get your user id like this, self.request.user.pk. It returns the user id

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis as i said above what i want is not the logged user but every users id who created a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
return Post.objects.filter(author_id=int(self.kwargs['slug'])).order_by('created_on')
```

If the slug is the user id then that should work.

If the slug is instead the name of the author then you can use the username slug provided by the url conf but you need to compare it to Author names in the database. Depending on the Author model you could use something like:

```
return Post.objects.filter(author__name=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('created_on')
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. My slug is the author_id but i get an error called ValueError "invalid literal for int() with base 10" . I guess it expects an integer and i pass a string?

Comment: Oh, okay, I updated my answer to convert it to an int.